# No visible @interface for 'UIColor' declares the selector 'blendedColorWithFraction:ofColor:'

Tags: ios, uicolor, cagradientlayer

```
//// General Declarations
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//// Color Declarations
UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.623 green: 0.61 blue: 0.61 alpha: 1];

//// Gradient Declarations
CGFloat gradientLocations[] = {0.62, 0.9, 1};
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)@[(id)UIColor.whiteColor.CGColor, (id)[UIColor.whiteColor blendedColorWithFraction: 0.5 ofColor: UIColor.blackColor].CGColor, (id)UIColor.blackColor.CGColor], gradientLocations);
```

I am using a Tool, where I am making Path and applying gradient. As I copy paste this code to Xcode, it tells that there is no it doesn't exist.

What is alternate method, which I can use instead of this.

Following is screenshot of error.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: it looks like that's only available for OSX, not iOS https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSColor/blendedColorWithFraction:ofColor:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is correct. `blendedColorWithFraction:ofColor:` is an [NSColor method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSColor/blendedColorWithFraction:ofColor:), not a UIColor method.

Comment: What is alternative, and what this method is supposed to do?

Comment: If you don't know what it is supposed to do, why are you trying to use it?

Comment: cagradient over cashapelayer, so I could get colors from dark to white.

Comment: see the last line

What is alternate method, which I can use instead of this.

Comment: can you come on discussion. I have one thing to discuss with you.